# Disable property on Visual Studio Properties Panel

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm new with wpf. I am currently developing custom control, and I want certain properties to be defined strictly from xaml. Example for what I'm trying to achieve is the Effect property, which only shows "Value must be set in XAML" text. Could someone tell me how to do that, or which attribute should I use? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hide properties from Properties Panel you can achieve it with BrowsableAttribute:

[BrowsableAttribute Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.browsableattribute%28VS.71%29.aspx)

*A visual designer typically displays in the Properties window those members that either have no browsable attribute or are marked with the BrowsableAttribute constructor of the value true. These members can be modified at design time. **Members marked with the BrowsableAttribute constructor of the value false are not appropriate for design-time editing and therefore are not displayed in a visual designer**. The default is true.*

```
[Browsable(false)]
public int HiddenProperty {
    get {
        // Insert code here.
        return 0;
    }
    set {
        // Insert code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: Setting Browsable to false will make it completely hidden, which means while using designer, user might not know that it exist. I want to have it to still showing on the Properties Panel, but user must type in the XAML code to set the value.

Comment: Ok. Then you would need to use another attribute to change the designer whih is going to be used when you edit the property in the Properties Panel. I've used it in the past but right now I don't have access to that codebase and find its name.

Comment: I was unable to check it in code but as far as I remember combination of TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute and CustomTypeDescriptor is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

You need dependancy properties

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752914.aspx

```
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsSpinningProperty = 
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "IsSpinning", typeof(Boolean),...);

public bool IsSpinning
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(IsSpinningProperty); }
    set { SetValue(IsSpinningProperty, value); }
}
```

Or simply add the effect to the xaml of yuor new control:

```
<local:NewControl>
    <local:NewControl.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect/>
    </local:NewControl.Effect>
</local:NewControl>
```

Comment: I am using DependencyProperty. What I want to achieve is so that user cannot edit its value through Visual Studio Properties Panel.